# What collection to use for a rotating list of last actions?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a C# collection type that allow me to define a maximum capacity. I would like to add objects to this collection and when my capacity is reached the oldest object should be replaced by the new one.

Specifically, I would like to create a collection that memorizes my last 10 or 20 actions.

I already read articles on Google but I'm looking for answers from this community.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly simple type, so it would be much more useful to show us an implementation and ask questions about that. Asking for a library/tool is off topic according to the FAQ.

Comment: Your question is subject of discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298283/993547).

Comment: The type you're looking for is called [ring buffer/circular buffer/cyclic buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Answer (score 1):

The only fixed collection type in .NET is an array, so that is the only one meeting your requirement.

You can keep an index to do the rotating. You just have to remember what your next location to write to is.

Something like this:

```
int index = 0;
string[] collection = new string[10];

public void Write(string text)
{
    index %= collection.Length; // prevent overflowing

    collection[index++] = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not performance-sensitive, then you can use a generic collection `Queue`.
Here is the example wrapper which can solve your problem:

```
public class LimitedQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue;
    private readonly int _limit;

    public LimitedQueue(int limit)
    {
        _queue = new Queue<T>();
        _limit = limit;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (_queue.Count == _limit) _queue.Dequeue();
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return _queue.Dequeue();
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return _queue.Peek();
    }

    public T[] GetAll()
    {
        return _queue.ToArray();
    }
}
```

It is less performant than an array but it lets you do something useful things like getting all items from the `Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

The type you are describing I've always referred to as a FixedQueue or a fixed size FIFO. The idea is the first in first out but you discard the first out if the size is exceeded:

```
public class FixedQueue<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _innerQueue;
    private int _length;

    public FixedQueue(int length)
    {
        _length = length;
        _innerQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>(length);
    }  

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        lock (_innerQueue)
        {
            if (_innerQueue.Length == _length)
                _innerQueue.Dequeue();
            _innerQueue.Enqueue(obj);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (_innerQueue)
        {
            return _innerQueue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more oriented object solution with inheritance and you don't care about maintenance you can write this:

```
public class FixedQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    //private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _innerQueue;
    private int _capacity;

    public FixedQueue(int capacity) : base()
    {
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            if (this.Count == _capacity)
                base.Dequeue();
            base.Enqueue(obj);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            return this.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

this solution doesn't respect the new trend that says you should prefer composition over inheritance.